# celery task not sent or executed

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I'm new to learning celery and was following tutorials and setup my celery setup with docker
I'm having issue with sending and executing celery task.

So have 4 docker container one for rabbitmq server, celery producer server and 2 worker.

Celery tasks file:

```
"""
CELERY MAIN FILE
"""

from celery import Celery
from time import sleep

celery_obj = Celery()
celery_obj.config_from_object('celery_config') #config file we created in same folder


@celery_obj.task
def add(num1,num2):
    print("executing add function")
    sleep(5)
    return num1 + num2
```

My celery config file for Producer:

```
"""
CELERY CONFIGURATION FILE
"""

from kombu import Exchange, Queue


broker_url = "pyamqp://rabbitmq_user:123@172.17.0.2/res_opt_rabbitmq_vhost"
result_backend = 'rpc://'
#celery_result_backend = ""
celery_imports = ('res_opt_code.tasks')

task_queues = (
    Queue('worker_A_kombu_queue',Exchange('celery',type='direct'),routing_key='worker_A_rabbitmq_queue'),
    Queue('worker_B_kombu_queue',Exchange('celery',type='direct'),routing_key='worker_B_rabbitmq_queue')
)
```

Config file for worker_A:

```
"""
CELERY CONFIGURATION FILE
"""

from kombu import Exchange, Queue


broker_url = "pyamqp://rabbitmq_user:123@172.17.0.2/res_opt_rabbitmq_vhost"
result_backend = 'rpc://'
#celery_result_backend = ""
celery_imports = ('worker_code.tasks')

task_queues = (
    Queue('worker_A_kombu_queue',Exchange('celery',type='direct'),routing_key='worker_A_rabbitmq_queue'),
    Queue('worker_B_kombu_queue',Exchange('celery',type='direct'),routing_key='worker_B_rabbitmq_queue')
)
```

Command for starting celery on producer:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=DEBUG -f log_file.txt
```

command for starting celery on worker:

```
celery -A tasks worker -n celery_worker_A -Q worker_A_kombu_queue --loglevel=DEBUG
```

Function call from producer:

```
from tasks import add
add.apply_async([4,4],routing_key='worker_A_rabbitmq_queue')
```

#also tried local executing the function but not logs of functions it's in pending

```
add.delay(4,4)
```

could you guyz please help me what I'm doing wrong here
In Logs I'm able to see worker_A connected but no logs for function

Comment: Just was troubleshooting and found out when I'm adding the task using apply_async it gets added in celery queue in Rabbitmq but here celery is an exchange

Answer (score 0):

Tried further troubleshooting and changed the argument in apply_async from routing key to queue and it working with the queue argument

was following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TM1a3m65zaA
old:

```
add.apply_async([4,4],routing_key='worker_A_rabbitmq_queue')
```

new:

```
add.apply_async([4,4],queue='worker_A_rabbitmq_queue')
```